# Why is the sticky header getting stuck?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been working on a website for a bit and have come across a problem for the sticky header. When you scroll down it gets caught at the bottom of the hero image, and I have absolutely no clue why it's doing this [Here is the issue in action (not promotion)](https://tabogachi.github.io/). All help appreciated, and sorry for a really long list of code.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

body, html{
    margin: 0;
    font-family: HebrewRegular;
    background-color: white;
    height: 100%;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: HebrewRegular;
    src: url("Adobe Hebrew Regular.otf") format("opentype");
    font-weight: bold;
}

.top-container{
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("Images/thai.png");
    height:100%;
    background-position-x: 50%;
    background-position-y: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}

.hero-text{
    text-align: center;
    position:absolute;
    top:40%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color:black;
    font-size: 45px;
    background-color: rgb(168, 123, 81);
    padding:15px;
}

.content1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: rgb(253, 207, 255);
  justify-content:center;

}

.content1 > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  height:400px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 20px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.content1 > div > h1{
  font-size: 35px;
}


.content1 > div > p{
  font-size: 15px;
}

.button5 {
  background-color: #555555;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.header {
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  color: #f1f1f1;
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  
}

.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 102px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header" id="myHeader">
            <img src = "Images/charmlogoTrans.png" width = "100px" height = "100px">
          </div>

       <div class = "top-container">
           <h1 class = "hero-text">Placeholder</h1>
       </div>

       <div class = "content1">
            <div class = "about">
                <img src = "https://picsum.photos/300/200">
                <h1>About</h1>
                <p>Learn more about Charm Thai</p>
                <a href="about.html" class="button"><button class="button5">About</button></a>
            </div>
            <div class = "menu">
                <img src = "https://picsum.photos/300/200">
                <h1>Menu</h1>
                <p>Check out our menu</p>
                <a href="menu.html" class="button"><button class="button5">Menu</button></a>
            </div>
            <div class = "contact">
                <img src = "https://picsum.photos/300/200">
                <h1>Contact</h1>
                <p class = "contactDesc">Find out how to contact us</p>
                <a href="contact.html" class="button"><button class="button5">Contact</button></a>
            </div>  
       </div>
p
<br>
p
<br>
p
<br>
p
<br>
p
<br>
p
<br>
p
<br>
p
<br>
p
<br>
p
<br>
p
<br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I inspect your code and I think because you have two conflicting classes the .header class is position:sticky and the class .sticky is fixed, you can try to remove the position sticky on the header and just let the .sticky be fixed like below. Let me know if this will work.

```css
header {
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    color: #f1f1f1;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header sticky" id="myHeader">
            <img src="Images/charmlogoTrans.png" width="100px" height="100px">
          </div>
```

Comment: That does fix the problem of the header getting stuck (thanks for that); But now at the top the header is glitching so that when you scroll is jumps down the screen.

Comment: it seems like you have a script upon looking at your code thats getting added on your header onscroll. you can just stick on one class and combined them instead of .sticky and .header remove the script (if you want) since you are just using it on sticking it on scroll and adding a class on scroll. you can attain that on just css unless you are planning on something.

Comment: you can try the above code and I think your glitch will get remove. But I would suggest just removing some js that can really attain on css. hope this helps, Let me know

Comment: Removing JS does nothing, and your code doesn't make it stick. Don't really know what to do.

Comment: I edited the code look above. you dont need to remove your js on that new code. Then let me know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244247/discussion-between-crystal-and-tabogachi).

Answer (score 1):

You should use position `fixed` instead of `sticky`. Along with that you also need to set the width to 100%.

With these changes, you don't need to have Javascript to handle the header position

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

body, html{
    margin: 0;
    font-family: HebrewRegular;
    background-color: white;
    height: 100%;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: HebrewRegular;
    src: url("Adobe Hebrew Regular.otf") format("opentype");
    font-weight: bold;
}

.top-container{
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("Images/thai.png");
    height:100%;
    background-position-x: 50%;
    background-position-y: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}

.hero-text{
    text-align: center;
    position:absolute;
    top:40%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color:black;
    font-size: 45px;
    background-color: rgb(168, 123, 81);
    padding:15px;
}

.content1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: rgb(253, 207, 255);
  justify-content:center;

}

.content1 > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  height:400px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 20px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.content1 > div > h1{
  font-size: 35px;
}


.content1 > div > p{
  font-size: 15px;
}

.button5 {
  background-color: #555555;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.header {
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  color: #f1f1f1;
  position: fixed; /* `sticky` to `fixed` */
  width: 100%; /* set the width 100% */
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="header" id="myHeader">
            <img src = "Images/charmlogoTrans.png" width = "100px" height = "100px">
          </div>

       <div class = "top-container">
           <h1 class = "hero-text">Placeholder</h1>
       </div>

       <div class = "content1">
            <div class = "about">
                <img src = "https://picsum.photos/300/200">
                <h1>About</h1>
                <p>Learn more about Charm Thai</p>
                <a href="about.html" class="button"><button class="button5">About</button></a>
            </div>
            <div class = "menu">
                <img src = "https://picsum.photos/300/200">
                <h1>Menu</h1>
                <p>Check out our menu</p>
                <a href="menu.html" class="button"><button class="button5">Menu</button></a>
            </div>
            <div class = "contact">
                <img src = "https://picsum.photos/300/200">
                <h1>Contact</h1>
                <p class = "contactDesc">Find out how to contact us</p>
                <a href="contact.html" class="button"><button class="button5">Contact</button></a>
            </div>  
       </div>
p
<br>
p
<br>
p
<br>
p
<br>
p
<br>
p
<br>
p
<br>
p
<br>
p
<br>
p
<br>
p
<br>
```